# Is there a similar function to 'melt' in reshape2 in R that works in MatLab?

Tags: r, matlab, melt

I'm trying to find a function in MatLab that is similar to the 'melt' function in the R package "reshape2", such that the row headers are repeated for each variable and stacked together.

e.g.:

If I have a matrix

```
A  1  2  3 
B  4  5  6
C  7  8  9
```

I'd like to change it to

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 4
B 5
B 6
C 7
C 8
C 9
```

Short of working a for() loop to go pair-wise through each column, is there a function that could do this?

Many thanks,
KRB

Comment: This depends on how you are defining the matrix.  Depending on how it is defined, different solutions are used to solve this problem. What is the code you used to define this matrix? MATLAB matrices by default don't support row headers, so what data type are you using to define this matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has `stack` and `unstack` functions, operating on tables, which are similar to `melt` and `cast`. Something like this would work

```
groups = {'A'; 'B'; 'C'};
A1 = [1; 4; 7];
A2 = [2; 5; 8];
A3 = [3 ; 6; 9];

T = table(groups, A1, A2, A3)
TLong = stack(T, 2:4)
```

which gives

```
TLong = 

    groups    A1_A2_A3_Indicator    A1_A2_A3
    ______    __________________    ________

    'A'       A1                    1       
    'A'       A2                    2       
    'A'       A3                    3       
    'B'       A1                    4       
    'B'       A2                    5       
    'B'       A3                    6       
    'C'       A1                    7       
    'C'       A2                    8       
    'C'       A3                    9
```

Note that your example matrix cannot exist in Matlab (or R) as matrices cannot contain strings or mixed types. I recommend you convert whatever structure you have now to a `table` if you want to use a inbuilt function.